# Reversing array using array name and reference to array

Tags: perl

I have declared an array, and a reference to that array like this: -

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my $aref = \@array;
```

Now, I'm trying to reverse the array, using the array name and the reference name.

```
print reverse @array, "\n";
print reverse @{$aref}, "\n";
```

This is working fine, and printing the reversed array in both the cases: -

```
4321
4321
```

However, if I try to print the reverse in the same line, its giving me a strange result: -

```
print reverse @array, reverse @{$aref}, "\n";
```

Now, I got this output: -

```
1234
4321
```

and if I add a newline in between: -

```
print reverse @array, "\n", reverse @{$aref}, "\n";
```

I got this output: -

```
1234

4321
```

**So, there are two problems as you can see: -**

- **1st,** The array is not getting reversed for using the name
- **2nd,** there is an extra newline getting printed between the two reversed array.

I can't understand this behaviour, why this could be happening. Also I went through the documentation of the function `reverse` to check whether there is mentioned any where about this behaviour, but I didn't dine any. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Running through `perl -MO=Deparse ...` helps you see what Perl is seeing more easily

Comment: @Zaid. Thanks for the command. Still remaining to study about various commands. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
reverse @digits, reverse @$digits, "\n"
```

means

```
reverse(@digits, reverse(@$digits, "\n"))
```

You want

```
reverse(@digits), reverse(@$digits), "\n"
```

or simply

```
reverse(@$digits, @digits), "\n"
```

Comment: Oh man. I forgot the rule that `parenthesis` can be removed where it does not change the meaning. :( Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Yeah It's working now. Will accept the answer once allowed. :)